# Subdomain to point to my SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, subdomain

Sorry if this seems like a silly or trivial question, but any work i've done with web servers and sql servers and other servers have always been with a local machine and never a remote one. So, I have a site/server that i'm in the progress of setting up and I want my SQL server to be accessible through a url. My current domain is http://www.MyLifeInDevelopment.com, I would like to access SQL through sql.MyLifeInDevelopment.com. How do I do this?

Comment: you don't really want to do that

Comment: Any particular reason? And whats the alternative?

Comment: Well you are exposing SQL Server to the internet, you should not do that. You should just expose the web server. The database should only be accessible by the web server, not the internet.

Comment: "Install databases in the secure zone of the corporate intranet and do not connect your SQL Servers directly to the Internet." See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144228.aspx

Comment: Ok so in a group setting, what is the best way for the team to use the same database. Or is it common practice to just have the same sata store structure on your local computer and if something changes then everybody has to change their local copy?

Answer (score 0):

[Donal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379855/donal) is correct in pointing out the security ramifications of doing what you ask. If having a subdomain for your SQL server is still something you wish to pursue you'll need to have access to the DNS zone for your domain. You can find more information about which DNS records you'll need at [this Server Fault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/275982/what-type-of-dns-record-do-i-need-to-make-a-sub-domain).